# Strategy in mql5

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, trading-systems

I have the following code(is not mine) in an Expert Advisor:

```
 if((Handle(DXHandle, 0) - Simbolo.Ask()) >= (DXPontosDistancia * _Point)){...}
```

Handle(DXHandle,0) is a function that returns the value of an moving average of seven candles of one minute. DXPontosDistancia is a value that they obtained from backtesting(is 140) and _Point is the pont of the active(in this case Bra50). If that condition is true, we make a buy operation. My question is: what is the point of that substraccion? Why we substract a moving average with the Ask Price?

Comment: So the signal to buy is thst the current ask is 140 below some moving average price. This is just trying to predict dips and buy them based on the value of 140,right?

Comment: @will This makes sense, but why subtraction, and not division.

Comment: @will 140 is value obtained in somebacktesting for Bra50. Yes. exactly. I didn' t see that i can pass one value to the other side of the inequity, thanks